# is there an endpoint we can query using a page access token and sending the feed targeting parameters to get estimated reach?

Tags: facebook, feed, facebook-insights, targeting

Is there an endpoint we can query using a page access token and sending the feed targeting parameters to get estimated reach?

There isn't anything documented about how to get to this information, although it is available to adgroups: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#targeting

Comment: What are you asking this data for? unless you specify what you are using data for, you are unlikely to get a good answer.

Comment: Is the [reach estimate endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/reachestimate/) in the ads API not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the Facebook Insights API? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/